# A dynamic sum formula - Excel

Tags: excel

Guys I am trying to write a dynamic sum formula where the array range starts from a cut-off date ( this date changes every month ).

I have the periods in the top first row *201801* in `A2`, *201802* in `B2` etc.
and starting from `A3` I have the sales' figures.

e.g. the cut-off date is *201806*, so I need my sum formula to be `=sum($F3:L3)`

what I was trying to do is `=sum(ADDRESS(3,MATCH($B$1,$A$2:$L$2,0),3):L3)`

`ADDRESS(3,MATCH($B$1,$A$2:$L$2,0),3)` returns `$F3` which does not work in the sum formula!

Comment: You just need and INDIRECT to convert to a range ref `=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,MATCH($B$1,$A$2:$L$2,0),3) &":L3"))`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INDIRECT` is [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation) so may not be the best function to use.

I take it that `L3` is static, and you're looking to sum from the lookup value to `L3`.

- `MATCH(201806,$2:$2,0)` will return the column number that *201806* first appears in.
- `INDEX($3:$3,,6):$L$3` will return a reference to `F$3:$L$3` (`F` being the sixth column - replace `6` with the `MATCH` function).
- `SUM(F$3:$L$3)` adds it all up.  Replace `F$3:$L$3` with the `INDEX`.

The final formula would be:

```
=SUM(INDEX($3:$3,,MATCH(201806,$2:$2,0)):$L$3)
```

Replace `201806` with a range reference.

If the end date is variable you can use another `INDEX` function to find it.
This finds the last date using the `MAX` function:

```
=SUM(INDEX($3:$3,,MATCH(201806,$2:$2,0)):INDEX($3:$3,,MATCH(MAX($2:$2),$2:$2,0)))
```

This adds from June to December:

```
=SUM(INDEX($3:$3,,MATCH(201806,$2:$2,0)):INDEX($3:$3,,MATCH(201812,$2:$2,0)))
```

Comment: Much Apprecaited!